# Magento2 Frontend and backend doesn't work while executing commands

Tags: magento-2.1.7, cli, ssh, command

Whenever I execute `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` commands from SSH, magento2 frontend and backend showing error. My magento2 store in production mode.

What should I do before run SSH command so that frontend/backend should be work while executing commands?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a native macrocosm of Magento 2.

As you know, when we are running commands specially compile and static content deploy command.

**Magento compiles each and every file with their assets and js and links to pub/static directory**.

**so when compilation is going on - it will shows the errors as all file are still not compiled/deployed so you only has the option to wait until command execution is completed for all the files.**

But for prevention you can **make/enable website maintenance mode** when you are running command.

**So customer of the website will see notice that website is in maintenance mode for few mins.**

Once command execution is completed **you can disabled maintenance mode for the same**.